# Cooldown operator in RxJS

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I am working on API requests which has rate limit and allows to batch the requests.

`buffer` is a good API to buffer the request, so that I can send a batch api after the cooldown (like 5 seconds). I need a good closing observable.

After several tries with `throttle`, `debounce`, and searching in stackoverflow, none of them succeed. I finally come up with custom operator to tackle this.

```js
function cooldown<T>(time: number) {
  return function (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      let lastTime = 0
      let timer: NodeJS.Timer
      function emit(value: T) {
        lastTime = Date.now()
        subscriber.next(value)
      }
      source.subscribe({
        next(value) {
          const duration = Date.now() - lastTime
          if (duration >= time) {
            emit(value)
          }
          else {
            if (timer)
              clearTimeout(timer)
            timer = setTimeout(() => emit(value), time - duration)
          }
        },
        error(error) {
          subscriber.error(error)
        },
        complete() {
          subscriber.complete()
        },
      })
    })
  }
}
```

so that I can use it in this way:

```js
requestObservable
  .pipe(
    buffer(
      requestObservable.pipe(
        throttleTime(100, undefined, { leading: false, trailing: true }), // batch more for the first request, don't want to send with only one
        cooldown(3000), // neither throttle nor debounce works here. Is it possible to replace it by some build-in operators to work the same?
      ),
    ),
  )
  .subscribe(async requests => {
    // send a request in batch
  }
```

I would like to know if this is possible to replace this operator by throttle or debounce? or is it the only way to do the job? Thanks.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Is it encouraging me to remove the code which only for better understanding my question? I am seeking an operator to work as cooldown closing observable, instead of reviewing my custom operator.

Comment: @shtse8 - the question probably belongs here. But to answer, I would need more information about the behavior you want to see.

Comment: @TobiasS. I should draw a timeline to explain but it's a tough work. Simply, at least n seconds cooldown time between two values except the first. emit last value if there is values emitted in the cooldown time. for example, 1 second per request, 3 seconds cooldown time, totally 5 requests on the first 5 seconds, which is 1s-2s-3s-4s-5s, the value emitted should be on 1s-----4s-----7s. if one more request come at 10s, the value should be emitted immediately on 10s because it already passed 3s from the 7s.

Answer (score 0):

[throttleTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttleTime)

```
requestObservable$.pipe(
  throttleTime(3000, asyncScheduler, { leading: true, trailing: true })
).subscribe(...);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ehqpbo?file=index.ts

Comment: throttleTime doesn't work because as you can see x (one's close) and c (one's open) is shorter than 3s.

Comment: The behavior of my `Stackblitz` example is what you want (like your comment).
If you want other behavior please provide more details. thx

Comment: @shtse8 - I realize that Marble Diagram maybe is wrong, but `throttleTime` still work on your behavior.